# laravel pluck 5.2 not works as in 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Code below was working in 5.1 and it was lazy loading logos. But now it tryin to call load method on Collection.

```
$campaigns = Campaign::all();
$campaigns->pluck('brand')->load('logo');
```

Error

```
in Macroable.php line 81
at Collection->__call('load', array('logo')) in HomeController.php line 84
at Collection->load('logo') in HomeController.php line 84
at HomeController->index(object(Request))
```

5.1 with wrong relation error

```
in Builder.php line 2071
at Builder->__call('logo1', array())
at Builder->logo1()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'logo1'), array()) in Builder.php line 943
at Builder->__call('logo1', array())
at Builder->logo1()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'logo1'), array()) in Model.php line 3483
at Model->__call('logo1', array()) in Builder.php line 477
at Brand->logo1() in Builder.php line 477
at Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Relation.php line 171
at Relation::noConstraints(object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 478
at Builder->getRelation('logo1') in Builder.php line 449
at Builder->loadRelation(array(object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand)), 'logo1', object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 429
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand), object(Brand))) in Collection.php line 44
at Collection->load('logo1') in HomeController.php line 82
```

Find out it was Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection and now Illuminate\Support\Collection.

How can i convert it to Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init a new Eloquent collection with pluck result and it worked again. I hope there is a better solution.

```
    $b = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($campaigns->pluck('brand'));
    $b->load('logo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections#introduction): as declared in the introduction note

> Note: While most Eloquent collection methods return a new instance of an Eloquent collection, the pluck, keys, zip, collapse, flatten and flip methods return a base collection instance.

The Eloquent Collection is just an extension of the Illuminate\Support\Collection. In the Eloquent Collection the constructor is not overridden so, checking the Base Controller constructor, we can assume that you can create an Eloquent Collection (or a new Base Collection) with this kind of type / instances:

- Array
- Collection (instance of *self*)
- Arrayable (instance of)
- Jsonable (instance of)
- JsonSerializable (instance of)

You can check the __construct method of the Collection class into your vendor folder, into laravel\framework\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php then search for the getArrayableItems method that's called into the constructor.

In my humble opinion, creating an Eloquent collection from a "base" collection is quite useless as you will lose the references to the database and you won't be able to directly work with that result set anymore. In fact, you won't have an id or any primary key that will let you identify a precise row into your database (unless your plucked data is the primary key). Anyway, you can instance a new Eloquent collection passing the "base" Collection in the constructor:

```
$baseCollection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection();
$eloquentCollection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($baseCollection);
```

Additionally, with Campaign::all() you are fetching all the columns from the table. Why don't you just

```
Campaign::with('logo')->get(['id', 'brand']);
```

The lazy load will make a query for each element in your collection. Instead, the eager loading will perform it in a quite faster way giving all the data you need in a minor number of query.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Campaign::all() is just for demonstration. And logo is not a reference to campaign, it belongs to brand. It seems like to initiate a new eloguent collection is the best choice.